# BottomNavigation component from Material UI doesn't stay at the bottom on screen resize

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have react app where I need to put a footer that stays at the bottom, all the time.

I rearrange the components on the screen based on screen size i.e I change the `display` from `flex` to `block` using media queries.

I have included the `<BottomNavigation />` component in the App.js file, just below the Routes like this.

```
<div>
        <NavBar/>
        <main className={style.container}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/data" component={Data} />
            <Route exact path="/productfeed" component={ProductFeed} />
            <Route exact path="/demo" component={Demo} />
            <Route exact path="/userAction" component={UserAction} />
            <Route exact path="/discoveryPath" component={DiscoveryPath} />
            <Route exact path="/conversionAnalysis" component={ConversionAnalysis} />
            <Route exact path="/performanceMonitor" component={PerformanceMonitor} />
            <Route exact path="/data" component={Data} />
            <Route exact path="/demo" component={Demo} />
            <Route exact path="/productFeed" component={ProductFeed} />
            <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        </Switch>
        <BottomNavigation className={style.footer} showlabel="">
                <p style={{width: '100%', textAlign: 'center'}}> My DashBoard </p>
        </BottomNavigation>
```

I used the following CSS for the footer/BottomNavigation component such as
 `position:fixed;`, `bottom:0;` and `clear: both;` as suggested in other answers but when I resize the window and trigger the media query which re-arranges the components on the screen. The `<BottomNavigation />` doesn't go all the way down, it stays in-between the components.

I also get a warning in the console when I use the `<BottomNavigation />`
like this

> Warning: React does not recognize the `showLabel` prop on a DOM
>   element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
>   attribute, spell it as lowercase `showlabel` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

position : sticky;
bottom : 0;

It worked in my case.